# Cannot kill recent task manager when Make home launcher application

Tags: java, android, samsung-galaxy, android-recents, android-api-30

I try to make home launcher application with this in manifest.xml

```
       <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

but When I press recent task button, recent task manager overlay on my app and cannot kill and cannot return to home launcher. (But some touch event is working)

I try to solve this with change task order, but it not worked

```
        ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getApplicationContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        activityManager.moveTaskToFront(getTaskId(), 0);
```

Is there same problome and solution in this case?

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem.
I still don't know reason, but stype option windowIsTranslucent was crush with system application. Then, I disable windowIsTranslucent, and solve it